# Wifi Card not Identified

Tags: wireless, drivers, macbook-pro

When I try `sudo lshw -C network` and look under "product" to find the specific model of wifi card I have, I see:

```
product: Broadcom Corporation
```

Does anyone know why I can't seem to get the actual model? For example, on my old ubuntu laptop i get

```
product: Wireless 7260
```

The computer I am using now is a macbook pro 12,1 that has just been dual booted with Ubuntu. I am trying to determine the model that is currently in use in order to get drivers for it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will get informaton by running

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
```